# Nonlinear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve 
$$y'(t)=\sin\left(\frac{1}{1-y(t)+t}\right)$$

If I substitute $v(t)=\frac{1}{1-y(t)+t}$,
then $y'(t)=\sin v(t)$,
then I have no idea to continue.

I have only learnt linear differential equations. Could you please lend me a helping hand?

Thank you for editing my question. 
Actually, the question is asking for the maximal interval of solution.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a parenthesis, but I assume you mean
$$y'(t) = \sin\left( \dfrac{1}{1-y(t)+t}\right)$$
If you substitute $v(t) = 1/(1 - y(t) + t)$, i.e. $y(t) = 1 - 1/v(t) + t$, then you should get
$$ \dfrac{v'(t)}{v(t)^2}  + 1 = \sin(v(t))$$
so that 
$$ v'(t) = v(t)^2 (\sin(v(t))-1) $$
This is a separable differential equation.  Divide by the right side and integrate:
$$ \int \dfrac{dv}{v(t)^2 (\sin(v(t))-1)} = \int dt = t + C $$
Unfortunately, the integral on the left can't be done in "closed form".

Comment: Thank you! The actual question is asking for the maximal interval of solution. What I have done so far is writing it in the separable form as what you did. Then I claim the integral of v as a function g, from the separable form. I claim that g(v(t))=t. Then g is the inverse of v. I am now trying to figure how to use this relation to figure out the interval of t.

Comment: Hint: Note that there are solutions $v(t) = constant$. These prevent $v$ from running off to infinity.